# Copy Database Structure of Mysql Database

Tags: mysql, database-design

I am using MySql 5.1 Database.

I have created a Project database. (Template Database)

and want to Create a copy of the same database from the Application, every time, User Creates A new Project.

How can I copy and Create a New Database of same structure?

What is the Command to do so?

Answer (score 18):

If you only want to copy the table structure etc. from one db to the other you can use this single bash line:

```
mysqldump -u user -ppass -d olddb | mysql -u user -ppass -Dnewdb
```

The new database must exist already. The -d flag in the mysqldump command prevents copying of data.

Answer (score 1):

Dump the database with the -d option.

To create a new copy, do a "create database new-database-name; use new-data-base-name;", then run the dump file as a sql script.

Comment: How can I do the same?? can we copy n create a new structure with single command??

Comment: No. In fact the dump file will issue one command per structure (table, view, sp, index, etc.).

Answer (score -1):

Check out the SHOW CREATE TABLE command:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-create-table.html
It will return the create command used to create the given table.