# Rename DB and Copy DB Structure to new DB - MySQL & PHP or Ruby

Tags: php, mysql

Reference: [Copy Database Sructure of Mysql Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771253/copy-database-sructure-of-mysql-database)

Here's my problem... I have a site that I use PPC to drive traffic to. I track the visitors' keyword, PPC source, ad versions, etc. Currently I store this data in a MySQL DB (InnoDB) named `visits`. However, when this PPC campaign is running full throttle it generates a lot of data. Every so often my site crashes because this DB fills up and stops responding. (And because I forget to manually do a copy and empty...)

So now I want to create a PHP or Ruby script that runs once a week/month to put the gathered data into an archive DB and empty the DB used for data collection. I assume the fastest way is to rename the existing DB `visits` to something with a date stamp in the name like `visits_010113_020113` for the month of Jan 2013. Then copy create a new `visits` with only the structure. The primary key is 32 char hash generated by PHP's md5 function so duplicate keys due to auto-increment is not an issue.

(I chose a DB to store the data in because I'm familiar with DBs and I wanted to be able to parse data for custom reporting. I am open to suggestions of a different architecture but I don't want to be spending the next 3 weeks coding up new classes and such for a new architecture right now.)

I ran a Google search on copying the structure of a DB to a new DB (the first result is the one I referenced above and most of the rest of the first page were very similar). However, the solutions all use mysqldump through the CLI. I want to do everything via PHP or Ruby. I could use an SSH class I have for PHP to execute the CLI but that seems like a hack.

I was hoping there was a simple SQL statement I could pass to do the renaming and copying. My preferred solution would be entirely in PHP. I use PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 with Suhosin-Patch, mysql 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2, and Ubuntu 12.04 server. I also use PHP's PDO object to interface with MySQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this would require you to have a list of the tables that need to be copied, but I like

```
CREATE TABLE cur_db.tbl_name LIKE old_db.tbl_name
```

So your script could rename the DB, create the new db, then run this in a loop over your table names.

Comment: I meant to include that I don't know how to rename a DB either. I tried `CREATE DATABASE visits_struct / DROP DATABASE visits_template` per phpmyadmin as a test but that didn't work. As far as the `CREATE TABLE` statement goes, I could get a list via `SHOW TABLES` and there are only 4 tables so that shouldn't be an issue for this DB. I couldn't see it becoming an issue until there were thousands of tables but maybe I'm wrong. It would be nice if there was a single SQL statement to do it but this is certainly better than nothing. Thanks

Comment: @gabe - I forgot that MySQL doesn't provide a good rename DB command, But that might actually make this easier. So you need to copy your DB. 1) You create the new db 2) using the `CREATE x LIKE y` you make all your tables 3) use `INSERT into y SELECT * FROM x` to populate those tables 4) `TRUNCATE TABLE x` to reset your existing DB's tables back to fresh. There is no single SQL statement that will do this unfortunately. Apparently they tried and it was too buggy and resulted in lost data.

Comment: Thanks... I had hoped there would be a nice clean way to do this via SQL Statements (1-3 of them) without a loop. Oh well, can't always get what you want.